# Remove [.net-5.0] tag and merge them into [.net-core]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

We have [26 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-5.0) tagged with [.net-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-5.0), but the naming is wrong - both [ASP.NET 5.0 and .NET 5.0 became respectively ASP.NET Core and .NET Core](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx), so the presence of the tag is unnecessary, it can be a synonym.

Also, we have [100 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net5) tagged with [asp-net5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-net5), and they should be merged into [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) with adding the synonym as well.

Comment: You can retag them just fine. Is there any danger that these tags would be exhumed?

Comment: When I created this question, I thought that these tags should be merged into. No, there is no such danger, as far as I know - .Net Core is already 2.0, and keeps going.

Comment: They do not need to be manually retagged, and *should not be*. If a merge is appropriate, a moderator can do so. So far, there is only one vote in agreement with this. That's not enough consensus for a moderator to take action.

Comment: @CodyGray could you stop rebutting my point of views *without* making me aware. It's **rude**.

Comment: I wasn't attempting to reply directly to you, @Braiam. It isn't necessary to have an argument each time you disagree with someone.

Comment: @CodyGray "You can retag them just fine" "They do not need to be manually retagged" how is not that a direct disagreement towards my point of view? You may not be trying to answer me, but you are addressing the idea I am presenting.

Comment: You should notice, though, that in the future `.net 5.0` might exist, just as `ASP.NET 5` (as an upgrade to the existing `ASP.NET 4.5`)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that sounds like a very good reason to manually review these questions.

Comment: @Braiam Not really, because that's an unlikely future, there's nothing to support that for now. I mentioned that only so that they are not taken "as the same" (if that's possible). No single question, today, can be referring to that because it just does not exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should refer to this post from [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx):

- ASP.NET 5 is now ASP.NET Core 1.0.
- .NET Core 5 is now .NET Core 1.0.
- Entity Framework 7 is now Entity Framework Core 1.0 or EF Core 1.0 colloquially.

From my understanding, there *may* be a .NET 5 in the future (although *I* wouldn't bet a lot of money on it).

Answer (score 3):

All in all, here is the result:

- a synonym [asp.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-5) for [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) has been created
- questions with [.net-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-5.0) were revised and retagged

In future, in case of `.Net-5.0` actually being place, that tag should be used again.

Comment: Hmm. The [[tag:asp.net-5]] <- [[tag:asp.net-core]] synonym was created back in January of 2016. That wasn't something done recently.

Comment: I didn't see that, that's why I created this question

Answer (score -1):

I have misgivings about this request (the .net core one)... are these really questions about .net-core:

- [How to resolve %DNX_PATH% in development environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35054807/792066)
- [EF7, Loading child entities with order by, does not load child entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35449762/792066)

To my very untrained eye, there's nothing on those two questions that suggest that they are core related. Also, it doesn't help that this tag has been, for all purposes, abandoned. From it's inception, it has got at most 2 question per month, the latest one in 2016-04-11, **more than a year ago**. [It's most upvoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28333034/792066) doesn't even relate to the .net release, but about the lack of an azure component, which problems are unrelated to the core architecture.

So, at least for .net-5.0 tag, it's not a clear cut case. Manual review *is required*, which is not at all difficult, given it's less than 30 questions.

Comment: Should I create a separate question for the asp.net?

Comment: @VMAtm I suggest instead to actually review those questions and verify if the request indeed makes sense.

Comment: "To my very untrained eye, there's nothing on those two questions that suggest that they are core related."... DNX => .NET Core. EF7 => EF Core (not necessarily .NET Core though, but the post says so)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Are you sure DNX always imply .net core? Isn't it more ASP.NET Core which can run on .net or core?

Comment: @Braiam I'm sure: " DNX **was** a runtime and a toolset used to build .NET Core and, more specifically, ASP.NET Core 1.0 applications" It does not even exist anymore

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto oh, then maybe we don't need those questions to exist anymore either...

Comment: Exactly, `DNX` was removed and only really existed during the `RC` phase of `.NET Core`. If you use it, you are using unsupported frameworks

Comment: but IMHO that fact should not have any impact on how we handle _tagging_. If DNX indicates Core's RC, so that's still Core's topic.