# Untangling the twisted [.net]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[Previously on](https://youtu.be/eX-BCKutDh0) Meta: [.NET 5.0 and ASP.NET Core 5.0 tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400924/net-5-0-and-asp-net-core-5-0-tags).

The tl;dr is that going forward, Microsoft has decreed that ".NET Core" shall be called simply ".NET" to indicate it is the future path of that ecosystem. What was previously called ".NET" will be renamed to ".NET Framework" to reflect that Framework is a discrete and legacy product.

This creates a problem around the various .NET tags on Stack Overflow - for example, the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag with over 300,000 questions has existed forever and is currently used to refer to the .NET ecosystem as a whole, not the new hotness.

I propose the following as a possible way to sort out this mess:

- Un-synonymize [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) and [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) so that the former is left with all 307k questions, while the latter is empty.
- Rename [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) to [.net-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-platform); this will encompass the .NET ecosystem as a whole (.NET, .NET Core, .NET Framework). Update tag description to this effect. (This will also ensure that everyone who is currently watching [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) will now be watching [.net-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-platform) instead.)
- Create a **new** [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) that's only to be used for questions relating to the current and future versions of .NET (i.e. 5, 6, and whatever comes next). Add usage guidance to this effect.
- Add usage guidance to [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) to indicate it should be used only when the question applies to .NET Core 1.x, 2.x, 3.x.
- Add usage guidance to [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) to indicate it should be used only when the question applies to a version of the .NET Framework.
- Add related tags to [.net-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-platform): [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core), [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework).
- Apply these tags sanely going forward.

Unless I've grossly misunderstood something and/or the Stack Overflow platform doesn't support the above, the only downside will be that browser history and bookmarks that currently point to the .NET ecosystem will now point to "new" .NET. Not a biggie, in my books.

Comment: No matter what we do, this situation is going to be painful for years to come....

Comment: I agree with most of these but I'm not sure if [.net-platform] is even necessary. _"everyone who is currently watching [.net] will now be watching [.net-platform] instead"_ -- I think they should be watching [.net-framework] instead (which is what [.net] currently represents).

Comment: This seems generally reasonable, though a link to Microsoft's information on this change would be helpful for context.

Comment: How about adding something like "legacy" to the old tags? It's not a *good* solution, but it might have the fewest unintended consequences.

Comment: Microsoft has shown to be *incredibly* bad with naming (looking at you, "ASP.NET Core" that is using .NET Framework, not Core), so we should expect them to screw up anything you can come up with in probably the next year or two by naming something completely unrelated ".NET", too.

Comment: Can we just call everything .net and be done with it. That way we are sure that whatever MS does, we are partially correct.

Comment: I totally agree. I have made in the past two proposals to deal with this subject (including renaming .net to .net-framewor), but both were heavily downvoted and deleted. Many new users are using the `.net` tag to talk about .NET 5, when currently the tag is only intended to .NET Framework.

Comment: @Braiam I have tried in the past making a proposal following that direction, following [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400980/5762332), but it was heavily downvoted and folks argued that .NET Framework and .NET [Core] are two different things and should not be throwed on the same basket.

Comment: @nvoigt They'll introduce a thing that's called ".net platform", right? Just to mess with this proposal :-)

Comment: I don't know anything about this ecosystem, but is the "new .net" sufficiently different from the "old .net core"? If not, I'd even synonymise them, and put "*formerly known as .NET Core (until v3)*" in the tag description of [tag:.net].

Comment: I would expand @Magnetron's argument in that over the past 15 years I've seen new users use `.net` to talk about _anything_ related to various versions of the frameworks, so I'd agree with everything except [tag:.net-platform] for the generic platform, that seems like an unrealistic dream.

Comment: inb4 .NET# and a new C## implementation

Comment: @Bergi Yes, unfortunately, it is sufficiently different (it's a whole rewrite; .NET was Windows-only, then .NET Core was invented as a cross-platform successor, being brought up to feature parity w/ .NET. But .NET was not discontinued and continued being developed, so at this point they have effectively discontinued .NET and said the next version of .NET Core will be the only new version and it will just be called .NET).

Comment: .NET 5 is the next version of .NET Core and renaming it is more marketing than technical.  There's a huge and growing overlap between .NET Framework and .NET Core (netstandard).   New functionality going forward will often be shipped as netstandard NuGet packages, which will run on both Framework and Core.  Sometimes doing nothing is the best option, especially as Microsoft has a track record of renaming things (OLE, ActiveX, COM) and even "undeprecating" what they previously deprecated: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This harkens back to the old days where MS added ".NET" to *everything*, even if it had absolutely nothing to do with what we now call .NET Framework -- much as "Azure" is being used today even if something doesn't live in a cloud. As a tag, `.net` was, is and will remain worthless anyway; you can do with it what you like as long as you don't make the mistake of thinking it's successfully going to refer to anything specific. In particular not .NET Coreframework/Frameworkcore 5+.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: "When I use a word," Microsoft said, in rather a scornful tone, "it means just what I choose it to mean - neither more nor less." "The question is," said Apple, "whether you can make words mean so many different things, without first putting an 'i' before them." "The question is," said Google, "who is to be The Mostest Evil - that's all."

Comment: Here comes `.Net 6` https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022/#net

Comment: "untangling" (sorry, I didn't know the word)...: => _make (something complicated or confusing) easier to understand or deal with._ // Hum OK, used in the Title on purpose then I suppose, even if it feels the opposite, but OK, fair enough...

Answer (score 22):

[I mostly agree](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406074/merge-tags-net-4-8-and-net-framework-4-8/406130#406130), *except* on your .net-platform point. The [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag is sufficient; [.net-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-platform) isn't a term I or anyone I know has used (not saying it's incorrect but certainly unfamiliar). [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) as an ecosystem won't conflict with specific future versions of .net since those will all have version postfixes (e.g. [.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-5)).

Microsoft [does refer to .NET](https://github.com/dotnet) as a "[developer platform](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/)". However, I don't think most users will pick up on that, and will more likely opt for [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) as the general ecosystem tag.

#### Update

@jwdonahue pointed out that Microsoft does use the term ".NET Platform". However, I still hold that most users won't use that term and will instead opt for [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net). To reconcile this, **either [.net-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-platform) should redirect to [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) or vice-versa** (I expect some of us will have strong opinions in either direction here). ".NET" is more familiar, but ".NET Platform" might be more accurate and official.

Comment: And how do we differentiate questions about the .NET [Core] from questions general to .NET [Core]/Framework/Standard? Or you're meaning `.net` to be used to .NET [Core] with no tag to the ecossystem?

Comment: .net is an all-encompassing ecosystem, .net-x (-core-x, -framework-x) refers to a version.

Comment: Agree on not having .net-platform. I've never used that term since .NET came out. I've rarely heard any other .NET developer use that term, and when they did, they were really talking about the CLR.

Comment: Agree. We should have the general tag `.net` for watchers, and if needed add the version tag. That way, the tags `.net-framework` and `.net-core` should not be used for new questions, but the version tag instead.

Comment: " `.net` as an ecosystem won't conflict with specific future versions of .net" - but it *will* conflict with using `.net` as a meta-tag to refer to anything about .NET 5, 6, and/or future - in the same way that [tag:.net-framework] is a meta-tag referring to anything about the Framework, and [tag:.net-core] (should) be a meta-tag referring to anything about .NET Core 1.x, 2.x, 3.x. I don't particularly like the ".net-platform" nomenclature but it's the only thing I could come up with other than ".net-ecosystem" (see unsolved problems in programming, #2).

Comment: @Ian, you aren't wrong, but that's more Microsoft's prerogative. Even if we did try to disambiguate by inventing new terms for these, users will still opt for the familiar terms and (according to your system) misuse those tags. The safest method is to follow the official naming applied by MS, however unfortunate.

Comment: +1 It will blow over.  WPF was going to be the new best thing... until it wasn't, and winforms kept steaming along.  Then UWP was going to be the new best thing... until it wasn't, and winforms kept steaming along.  .NET Core is the new best thing... until it's not, and the "legacy" framework keeps steaming along.

Comment: [.NET Platform](https://github.com/dotnet) is a thing.

Answer (score 2):

MS have proven that over the year they will change with little notice the *name* of the current flavour of the framework, the constant is that they are all some form of `.net` so instead of `.net-platform`, if you had an all-encompassing tag, it should be `.net`. We can assume that MS will stick with some form of `.net-vNext` for the next version after `.net-5`. We can therfore assume that with each release the meaning of what is `.net` is only going to get more ambiguous, and certainly not less.

> It is wrong to refer to all the `.net` versions as an *ecosystem*, because at no point do any of them really co-exist, with the almost exception of `.net-core` and `.net-standard`

Each version of the CLR has specific dependencies, naming and operation contexts that mean in many cases syntax for the same problem isn't compatible in other versions.

> `.net-platform` then is not helpful as it's own tag, you would either be searching for a solution in a specific version of the CLR *OR* you would be searching for assistance on a language or syntax specific issue, in this case `C#`, `VB` or `F#` tags would suffice.

I don't think there is a good argument to use `.net` for anything moving forward. All past and future derivatives of .Net have more specificity in their associated tag and .Net developers will always be searching for the version specific tag that matches their needs.

I would therefor counter your suggested actions with this:

- rename `.net` to `.net-framework`

  - if anyone is still watching the whole of `.net` then this is probably because they set the tag before the CLR rewrite, tag guidance should be updated to reflect that watchers should use the CLR version specific tag and that they should use a language specific tag if they need a more generic filter.
- add usage guidance to `.net-framework` to indicate that it should only apply to the legacy versions of .Net <= 4.8

  - If the specific major version is known, then the relevant tag should also be used such as `.net-2.0`, `.net-3.5`, `.net-4.5` where major and behaviour or pattern changing language and platform features were introduced.
- Add usage guidance to `.net-core` to indicate it should be used only when the question applies to .NET Core 1.x, 2.x, 3.x.
- implement `.net-5` for the *current* new version of .Net. This is consistent with language used around many past and present blogs, it matches version numbering and allows for future variations to be specifically versioned and tagged as we all evolve.

Comment: So we will have the tag `.net-framework` for all .NET Framework family and `.net-core` for all .NET Core family but not one for the current .NET X family? It should either have a tag for the whole .NET ecosystem or one for the .NET X family, otherwise, instead of watch the `.net` tag we will have to watch `.net-5`, `.net-6`, `.net-7`, `.net-8`...

Comment: Not having .net as a tag is not feasible without blacklisting it, I think

Comment: With the .Net frameworks (so <= 4.8) the code and namespaces were consitent, each new version was forward compatible, especially from a code example point of view. So it makes sense now looking back to refer to them as a single isolated set. You could also easily upgrade your code in-place to target the newer framework if you needed to access newer features. The changes since then are more substantial as the base namespaces have fundamentally changed.

Answer (score 1):

When Microsoft has ditched the "Core" in its nomenclature to underline that the Core technology will be the future going forward, they apparently meant it.

They are pushing hard on every front to get any newly written code moved to .NET 6+. It also seems like the development of the .NET Framework has grounded to a halt; during the heydays of .NET Framework from 4.5 in 2013 to 4.8 in 2019, version releases were spaced apart 270 days on average. It took a whopping 1209 days - more than 3 years - for 4.8.1 to be released. And apart from security and quality rollups, nothing has been announced regarding any updates to the framework for another 553 days now.

I see that - historically and encouraged by tag wiki and synonym definitions - the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag referred to [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework). **I don't think that should be the case for much longer.** It appears obvious to me that as time goes on, people saying or writing ".NET" will probably mean .NET 5+ etc., and not any of the .NET Framework versions 4.X. In my opinion, the tags should eventually reflect this, as Microsoft currently uses ".NET" terminology only ever in the context of the new .NET platform and has been for a few years now.

A quick check of current usage of [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) showed people using it were either referring to .NET 5+, or they were unclear about whether they are using .NET or the Framework. Some of them appeared to be oblivious to the fact that .NET Core exists and just knew ".NET" as the name of "the thingy I use". I couldn't find a single question that used the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag and unambiguosly meant the .NET Framework version 4.X.

In light of this, I would suggest as versionless-tags:

- `.net` with synonyms `dotnet`, `.net-core`, `.net-platform`
- `.net-framework` with synonyms `dotnet-framework`
- `.net-standard` with synonyms `dotnet-standard`

And as versioned tags:

- `.net-core-1.0`
- `.net-core-1.1`
- `.net-core-2.0`
- `.net-core-2.1`
- `.net-core-2.2`
- `.net-core-3.0`
- `.net-core-3.1`
- `.net-5`
- `.net-6`
- `.net-7`
- `.net-8`
- `.net-framework-3.5`
- `.net-framework-4.0`
- `.net-framework-4.5`
- `.net-framework-4.5.1`
- `.net-framework-4.5.2`
- `.net-framework-4.6`
- `.net-framework-4.6.1`
- `.net-framework-4.6.2`
- `.net-framework-4.7`
- `.net-framework-4.7.1`
- `.net-framework-4.7.2`
- `.net-framework-4.8`
- `.net-framework-4.8.1`
- `.net-standard-1.0`
- `.net-standard-1.1`
- `.net-standard-1.2`
- `.net-standard-1.3`
- `.net-standard-1.4`
- `.net-standard-1.5`
- `.net-standard-2.0`
- `.net-standard-2.1`

It would be up for debate whether the current tags such as `.net-4.8` with synonyms like `.net-framework-4.8` should exist this way around, the other way around, or only one of the two. Personally, I would rename the short ones to the longer form and refrain from re-adding the short ones as synonyms. I would generally avoid synonyms for all versioned tags, because it doesn't help with clarity when the same tag-name-syntax is used for wildly different technologies making them look like the differences between `.net.4-5`, `.net-4.8` and `.net-5` are all simple version changes of the same technology.

There's a good reason why there are no cross-over synonyms for [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) and [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) sub-tags either, so why should we create cross-over synonyms for `.net-framework` and `.net`?

Comment: I absolutely agree with this, and the problem goes even further with the related [ASP.NET (Core)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403720/can-we-disambiguate-the-asp-net5-tag) and [EF (Core)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315077/what-will-become-of-asp-net-5-and-entity-framework-7-tags) tags. Honestly, I think that we should have acted several few years ago, when the tags where still mostly applying to .NET Framework. Now we have got a very big mess, with alone the [.net] tag having thousands and thousands of questions which are likely a mix of all technologies.

Comment: Our options? Either leave it as it is and at most try to fix incoming questions, or get a significant amount of volunteers to work through some sort of prefiltered list of questions that are younger than a certain date and which don't have an unambiguous version tag. I'm in favor of the latter and would participate there myself, but given the general decline in curation participation and the necessary mod buy-in (there haven't been burninations for half a year) I'm somewhat pessimistic that we will get this done.

Comment: I love the idea. This would be a notable improvement for dotnet senior developers, Juniors won't see the difference.

Comment: Old questions with the tag `.net` are in majority about C#. I don't think we need to work on them.

Comment: “It also seems like the development of the .NET Framework has grounded to a halt” - They have…Microsoft open sourced the .NET Framework, called it .NET Core until it became a 1:1 replacement, and all development work is focused on the open source product. They literally blogged about the transition for years.

Comment: I wouldn't say .NET Core was a 1:1 replacement from the get-go. WPF for example was "only" introduced in Core 3.1, and several ASP.NET functions took a long time to get ported, too. Meanwhile, it's hard to find meaningful differences, which explains why continued development in the Framework is unlikely to happen.

Comment: You should post this as a separate question. It can't really be addressed fully/appropriately as an answer here to an existing question.

Comment: @TylerH Funnily enough this was first meant to be a question, but then I found 4 or five posts from different years ([2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357522), [2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390625), 2021 (this one), [2022](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420815)) around the .NET vs .NET-Core thingy and thought: the facts haven't changed, just more time has passed and ".net" being synonymous with the framework is less and less the case. Do we really need another post asking to align tag names with product names? If yes, I will do.

Comment: @janw I don't know if I could participate in tidying up (I always assumed re-tagging was a bot-action, and that renaming a tag would apply to all questions immediately), but if help is needed, I would volunteer as well.

Comment: What is next? ".NET Classic" to try to avoid some of the confusion? (Hopefully not causing even more confusion.) "ASP" became "[ASP Classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages)" even though ASP.NET wasn't renamed to "ASP" (probably because ASP.NET was shortened to ASP anyway in informal contexts).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't know... MS naming is... weird. Going from 3.1 to 5 to avoid version number clashes was a smart move. Ditching the "Core" was questionable, esp since they only did that for some products but not for others. Abolishing sub-versions and moving to an annual schedule is fine I guess, renaming "Current" to "STS" was very much needed, translating "STS" as "Standard -" instead of "Short Term Support" (in contrast to "LTS" = "Long Term Support") was a deliberate yet stupid idea. It's hit'n'miss, but we know from Windows 7, 8. 8.1, 10, 11 (10.0 internally)...

Comment: @LWChris Tag cleanups are generally a highly manual task: Volunteers go through all questions, edit them (and their answers) into shape, retag appropriately, and close-vote those that are unclear/off-topic. A mod can then potentially issue some bulk action to rename/synonymize/merge tags. If we want to do this, we probably need a new question post that analyzes the current situation and clearly outlines a plan what needs to be done, and how.